# Get a model reference from ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two Active Record Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecordd:Base
end
```

I would like to get the reference of the class *Post* from the activerecord association.

```
user.posts.get_object_class
```

Currently when I do

```
user.posts.class.to_s 
# Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
```

Is there a way I can get **Post** without having to "split" the string on "::" and then constantize it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `model` or `klass` attributes - it will return the constant you are looking for:

```
user.posts.model
#=> Post
user.posts.klass
#=> Post
```

See [apidocs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation) for more details.